# No implied relationship among the comparison operators

Tags: python, python-2.7

I recently started reading **[The Python Language Reference, Release 2.7.10](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/)**.

In ***Section 3.4: Special Method Names*** and particularly regarding the comparison operators `object.__eq__(self, other)` and `object.__ne__(self, other)` it states the following which has lead to some confusion:

> ***There are no implied relationships among the comparison operators. The truth of x==y does not imply that x!=y is false***. Accordingly, when defining **eq**(), one should also define **ne**() so that the operators will behave as expected.

---

What exactly does this statement mean? How can the truth of `x==y` not automatically and without question translate to a false value of `x!=y`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"no implied relationships" means that when you use "!=", if you haven't implemented `__ne__`, it's not going to instead call `__eq__` and negate the result. It will use the `__ne__` method inherited from its parent. Most of the time, this will resolve to `object.__ne__` which only checks for referential equality.

```
>>> class Fred:
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         print "eq was called!"
...         return False
...
>>> x = Fred()
>>> print x == 23
eq was called!
False
>>> #if eq and ne had an implied relationship, 
>>> #we'd expect this next line to also print "eq was called!"
>>> print x != 23
True
>>> #... but it doesn't.
```

It also means that you're free to define `__eq__` and `__ne__` in ways that seem mathematically contradictory. Python won't hold your hand.

```
>>> class Fred:
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return True
...     def __ne__(self, other):
...         return True
...
>>> x = Fred()
>>> print x == 23
True
>>> print x != 23
True
```

Although it does suggest that you *should* implement them in a mathematically sensible way. The above code block is legal, but not wise.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a contrived example that demonstrates one possible use of decoupling the two.

```
class Z7(object):

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self.x % 7 != other.x % 7
```

This lets us make a three-way distinction between two objects: numbers that are *exactly* equal (`==` returns `True`), numbers that are equal modulo 7 (`==` *and* `!=` return `False`), and numbers that are unequal modulo 7 (`!=` returns `True`).

```
if x == y:
    # E.g. Z7(3) == Z7(3)
    print("x and y are identical)"
elif x != y:
    # E.g. Z7(3) != Z7(5)
    print("x and y are unalike")
else:
    # Neither are true, so thy must be similar
    # E.g. Z7(3) and Z7(10)
    print("x and y are similar")
```

This doesn't use the 4th possibility, where `==` and `!=` both return `True`, which I cannot think of a good use for.